# Array assignment in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

What is possibly wrong with the following assignment and how should it be fixed

```
n = 1000
a = np.array ([8,9,0])
Anew= np.random.random((n,n))
Adash= np.zeros((n,n))+ np.diag(np.diag(Anew))
S = Anew[a,:][:,a]
Adash[a,:][:,a]= S
```

Here S is a non-zero array and Anew is also some non zero array the same size as Adash, but Adash doesn't change before and after assignment.

Comment: what is n, what is Anew? (can you give us an example which fails)

Comment: I think they are being picky about the hold. `unutbu` understood the question, and gave a good answer. Still it shouldn't be hard to edit the example - smaller `n`, define a `Anew`, specify the expected change in `Adash`.

Comment: Pity it's on hold since it is something I have rarely seen here. Any links to other questions regarding np.ix_ ? Since I can't find many I think this answer should be out there.It is not a debugging question but a conceptual one --this type of indexing comes up in a lot of machine learning applications. Answers about slicing and advanced integer indexing while abundant are useless here. I am very happy with @unutbu's answer and am twice as happy that they understood what I am asking without being picky about what the value of n is, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advanced indexing returns a copy**:

`Adash[a,:]` is using ["advanced integer indexing"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). Advanced indexing, as opposed to basic slicing, always returns a copy. So

`Adash[a,:][:,a] = ...` is modifying a copy, not a view, of `Adash` itself.

To add insult to injury, there is no reference to the copy returned by `Adash[a,:]` so the modification of the copy is also lost.

---

**Instead you could use [numpy.ix_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):**

```
Adash[np.ix_(a,a)] = S
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
n = 4
Anew = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
a = np.arange(3)
Adash = np.zeros((n, n)) + np.diag(np.diag(Anew))
S = Anew[a, :][:, a]

Adash[a, :][:, a] = S
print(Adash)

# [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
#  [  0.   5.   0.   0.]
#  [  0.   0.  10.   0.]
#  [  0.   0.   0.  15.]]

Adash[np.ix_(a,a)] = S
print(Adash)
# [[  0.   1.   2.   0.]
#  [  4.   5.   6.   0.]
#  [  8.   9.  10.   0.]
#  [  0.   0.   0.  15.]]
```

---

**Basic slices return a view:**

Alternatively, if you can replace the integer indexing array `a` with a basic slice, then `Adash[slice]` *will* return a view of `Adash`, and then  `Adash[slice][...] = val` modifies `Adash`:

```
Adash[:3, :3] = S
```

---

**More on why `Adash[a,:][:,a] = ...` does not modify Adash**:

Using two sets of brackets is called index chaining. 
Notice that when you express the assignment without index chaining then `Adash` is modified because `Adash[...] = val` causes `Adash.__setitem__` to be called.

In contrast, `Adash[a,:][:,a]` calls `Adash.__getitem__((a,slice(None)))` which returns a new array, let's call it `temp`, whose underlying data is copied from `Adash`. Then `temp.__setitem__((slice(None), a))` is called, which modifies `temp`. `Adash` never gets modified. Since there is no reference to `temp`, the temporary, newly created array, gets garbage collected.

---

PS. semicolons at the end of statements are unnecessary in Python.

Comment: Thanks! I am confused then why the following: U [:,a] = np.dot(U[:,a], V); works just fine and U is updated? Here V is just an array of appropriate size.

Comment: `U[...] = val` calls `U.__setitem__`, so it does modify `U`. It's the double set of brackets which cause a problem when the first set of brackets returns a copy rather than a view.

Comment: Ah I see thanks so much!! Do you have any suggestions for more efficient way of expressing U [:,a] = np.dot(U[:,a], V)? I didn't know of the np.ix function-- very useful.

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to improve `U[:,a] = np.dot(U[:,a], V)`. However, usually improvements in speed come from reworking the algorithm *in the large* -- e.g. expressing the entire calculation with fewer function calls on larger arrays -- not by micro-optimizing single expressions.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I can't really replace a with a basic slice-- np.arange(3) is just a dummy example, the actual array is essentially a large set of non consecutive numbers.

Comment: The `np.ix_` approach works with non consecutive `a=[0,2]`.